# Request not processed by the DispatcherServlet "HTTP Status 404 - /Mvcvalid/displayForm.html (requested resource not available)"

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, tomcat7

When i run my app on Tomcat 7.0 server 1st - my **index.jsp** file gets executed and after if i click the *LOGIN (href)* to **loginPage.jsp** it will not get executed.

I got the Following error in my TOMCAT as Requested resource not available.I have searched lot on this but still cant get rid if this.

Actually  was trying to validate my *loginPage.jsp* file using *java4sController.java and UserDetails.java classes.*

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">

<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


<servlet>
   <servlet-name>java4s</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>java4s</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>SRI PREM VALIDATION</title>
</head>
<body>
<font face="verdana" size="2">
   <a href="displayForm.html">Login..</a>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

java4s-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc

        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="java4s" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
       <property name="basename" value="props" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

java4sController.java

```
package java4s;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class Java4sController {    

        @RequestMapping(value="/displayForm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String helloWorld(ModelMap model) {
        UserDetails ud = new UserDetails();
         ud.setUser("");
         ud.setEmail("");
        model.addAttribute("userDetails",ud);
        return "loginPage"; 
    }


        @RequestMapping("/login")
        public String loginCheck(@Valid UserDetails userDetails, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "loginPage";
            } else {
                model.addAttribute("lfobj", userDetails);
                return "success";
            }
        }

}
```

UserDetails.java

> package java4s;   import javax.validation.constraints.Size;   import
>   org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email; import
>   org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty; import
>   org.hibernate.validator.constraints.URL;   public class UserDetails{
>
> ```
>     @NotEmpty
>     private String user;
>
>     @NotEmpty
>     @Email
>     private String email;        
>
>     @NotEmpty(message = "Phone should not be blank.")
>     @Size(min = 10,max = 10)
>     private String phone;
>
>     @NotEmpty(message = "Enter your blog URL")
>     @URL
>     private String blog;
>
>     public String getUser() {
>         return user;
>     }
>
>     public void setUser(String user) {
>         this.user = user;
>     }
>
>     public String getEmail() {
>         return email;
>     }
>
>     public void setEmail(String email) {
>         this.email = email;
>     }
>
>     public String getPhone() {
>         return phone;
>     }
>
>     public void setPhone(String phone) {
>         this.phone = phone;
>     }
>
>     public String getBlog() {
>         return blog;
>     }
>
>     public void setBlog(String blog) {
>         this.blog = blog;
>     }   }
> ```

my loginPage.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<html>
<head>
     <title>Spring3Example</title>
<style>
  .error {
      color: #EF1313;
      font-style: italic;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form:form action="login.html" commandName="userDetails">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><font face="verdana" size="2px">User</font></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
    <font face="verdana" size="2">
    <form:input path="user" /> <form:errors path="user"></form:errors>
    </font>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><font face="verdana" size="2px">Email</font></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
    <font face="verdana" size="2">
    <form:input path="email" /> <form:errors path="email"></form:errors>
    </font>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><font face="verdana" size="2px">Phone</font></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
    <font face="verdana" size="2">
    <form:input path="phone" /> <form:errors path="phone"></form:errors>
    </font>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><font face="verdana" size="2px">Blog</font></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
    <font face="verdana" size="2">
    <form:input path="blog" /> <form:errors path="blog"></form:errors>
    </font>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Error in my Tomcat7.0 . .

```
   HTTP Status 404 - /Mvcvalid/displayForm.htm

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /Mvcvalid/displayForm.htm

description The requested resource is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
```

Comment: from your code there is no any error. It work for me. Please check deployment of project is there any error in tomcat console ?

Comment: yes frnd in another app also tomcat shows the same error. .

Comment: Have you check that your project is deployed in tomcat successfully without error ?

Comment: yes there is no problem with the deployment - @Yagnesh

Comment: ok..i didnt find any other issue. may you change your requestmapping `displayForm` to `/displayForm` may this work.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing UserDetails as argument to the method of

```
@RequestMapping(value="displayForm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloWorld(UserDetails ud) {
        return "loginPage";            
    }
```

Hope this solves it.

Comment: cant get u ! Then how can i get values frm UserDetails

Comment: Just remove it from helloWorld method. You are not using it there. If you still want to use it, Spring must know how to inject that UserDetails into the method.

Comment: i removed it now but is still the same error. It is not get navigated to loginPage @Darshan

Comment: Is there any problem with the call "displayform" ?

Comment: add a forward slash like "/displayForm"

Comment: added a front slash too friend cant get clear.Same error-I guess there might be problem in this call frm servlet

Comment: Can you post stack trace of the error or exception you are getting.

Comment: You have posted the console log right uptil you get your server started. Post the exception stacktrace when you execute your application, when the request is delegated.

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /Mvcvalid/displayForm.htm

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /Mvcvalid/displayForm.htm

description The requested resource is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.42

Comment: Try removing .html extension in your request. If it solves it.

Comment: I tried your application in my localhost and it worked properly. Here's what i changed though, change the welcome file list from index.html to index.jsp. In your mapping file add "/" to displayForm i.e. "/displayForm". And lastly also check that your jsp folder is under WebContent folder and it contains all the jsps. This should work now.

Comment: yes frnd there is a prob with my tomcat7.I tried running an another app got same error